# Forcing positions for more tikzpictures in one diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-trees

I need to draw a figure in latex, I decided to use tikzpicture and tabular to be able to make all layers of the diagram centered, but the problem is that the resulting diagram was not aligned neatly.

This is my code:

```
\begin{figure} [ht!]
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (is-root) {is} [sibling distance=1.5cm]
        child {node {X}}
        child {node {precise }};
    \path (is-root) +(0,-2.5\tikzleveldistance)
    node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
& 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (is-root) {is} [sibling distance=2cm]
        child {node {X}}
        child {node {and}[sibling distance=1.5cm]
        child {node {exact}}
        child {node {accurate}}
    };
    \path (is-root) +(0,-2.5\tikzleveldistance)
    node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}
{$\Downarrow$}\\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (is-root) {if} [sibling distance=3cm]
        child {node {is} [sibling distance=2cm]
        child {node {X}}
        child {node {precise }
        }}
        child {node {is} [sibling distance=2cm]
        child {node {X} }
        child {node {and}[sibling distance=1.5cm]
            child {node {exact}}
            child {node {accurate}}
        }};
 ;

     \path (is-root) +(0,-2.5\tikzleveldistance)
     node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture}}  \\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}
{$\Downarrow$}     \\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}
{[\textit{X is precise}] $\Rightarrow$ [\textit{X is exact and accurate}]} \\   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The rules generation process}
\label{Rules-Gen}

\end{figure}
```

I would like the arrows, a bit longer and the are in the middle between the two trees in the top and matched the same level of 'if' the top of the below tree. Similarly for the other downarrow.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

`\downarrows` I draw with help of `arrows.meta` library and both merged with image in second row. For positioning of images the `baseline` option is used, for positioning arrows and images is used `positioning` library.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure} [ht!]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
    \hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \node (is-root) {is}
        child {node {X}}
        child {node {precise }};
    node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \node (is-root) {is} 
        child {node {X}}
        child {node {and}
        child {node {exact}}
        child {node {accurate}}
    };
    node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, 
    node distance=5mm,
    level 1/.style = {sibling distance=3cm},
    level 2/.style = {sibling distance=2cm} 
                        ]
    \draw[double equal sign distance,-Implies] (0,0) -> (0,-1) coordinate (start);
    \node[below=of start] (is-root) {if} 
        child {node {is}
        child {node {X}}
        child {node {precise }
        }}
        child {node {is}
        child {node {X} }
        child {node {and}
            child {node (extract) {exact}}
            child {node {accurate}}
        }};
    \draw[double equal sign distance,-Implies, shorten <=3mm,shorten >=3mm] 
        (is-root |- extract.south) -> ++(0,-1.6);
\end{tikzpicture}}          \\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{[\textit{X is precise}] $\Rightarrow$ 
                     [\textit{X is exact and accurate}]} \\   
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{The rules generation process}
\label{Rules-Gen}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why make it easy? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is, after all, a tree, so why not a Forest?

Note that there is no particular reason to do it this way except that it avoids having to code the sub-trees twice.

This version requires Forest 2.1. Let me know if you want a version for an earlier Forest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{amssymb,array}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    before packing={
      for nodewalk={fake={name=earoot},L}{tier=this},
      delay={
        for nodewalk={fake={name=cond},L}{tier=that},
      },
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      where content={}{
        if={>O_={!1.content}{}}{phantom}{no edge},
        if level=0{phantom}{
          calign with current edge,
          !1.edge+={-Implies, double, double distance=1.5pt},
        },
      }{}
    }
    [,
      [is, name=proot
        [X]
        [precise]
      ]
      [
        [
          [, tier=this
            [if, name=cond
              [, delay={replace by'=proot}]
              [
                [
                  [, tier=that
                    [{[X is precise] & $\Longrightarrow$ & [X is exact and accurate]}, font=\itshape, align={@{}R{40mm}cL{40mm}@{} }
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
              [, delay={replace by'=earoot}]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [is, name=earoot
        [X]
        [and
          [exact]
          [accurate]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
  \caption{The rules generation process}\label{fig:rgp}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest version]

## EDIT

For version 2.03 of Forest, replace

```
        if={>O_={!1.content}{}}{phantom}{no edge},
```

with

```
        if={strequal(content("!1"),"")}{phantom}{no edge},
```

for the same result. This probably works with v2 of Forest and later.

Comment: When the recent `forest will be available in MikTeX, I will test your answer, anyway +1 for it :)

Comment: It is egregious here, really, but I only answered to try it out. Your answer is surely the simpler solution ;).

Comment: package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator 'O' or 'O_' (in '>O_={!1.connect}{}')....

Comment: @lol745 You need to update your TeX installation, if TeX Live, or wait a few days and update, for MikTeX.

Comment: Can I get the picture as pdf format please! Still not working, I will take this as a pdf picture.

Comment: @lol745 Please see edit. It is not possible to upload PDF.